# Docker hangs while building react app while checking on core-js dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, docker, apple-silicon

Here is where the build stops. This is on an M1 Mac Mini but have tried to build in both arm64 and x86_64 terminals, result is the same.

```
npm info lifecycle @babel/plugin-transform-sticky-regex@7.14.5~postinstall: @babel/plugin-transform-sticky-regex@7.14.5
npm info lifecycle @babel/plugin-transform-template-literals@7.14.5~postinstall: @babel/plugin-transform-template-literals@7.14.5
npm info lifecycle @babel/plugin-transform-typeof-symbol@7.14.5~postinstall: @babel/plugin-transform-typeof-symbol@7.14.5
npm info lifecycle core-js@2.6.12~postinstall: core-js@2.6.12
 > core-js@2.6.12 postinstall /app/frontend/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/core-js
 > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
```

Happy to provide more information but at this point I'm struggling to find what's relevent. This is deeper into node than I'm used to going.

I should note that the build requires Node v12.20.2.

Comment: Try `npm rebuild core-js` before building

Comment: @DTan13 thanks for the reply! Added this line before the install command, still hangs in the same spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the reason I couldn't find discussion on this issue is because of how silly it is but my problem was simple.

I was trying to build with a docker image that didn't support x64.

-_-

If anyone else has a similar problem, just go find the dockerhub page for the image you are building from and double check that does in fact support the architecture your computer is running on.

Comment: I hit the same error when using buildx to build for a specific platform. Same issue in that the base container didn't have a container for that architecture. Huge thanks for updating your own question with an answer.